# How to create Paged Horizontal TableView where I can pass text to particular page

Tags: iphone, ios

I am dealing with a project where I have a horizontal paged table view and it is connected to a sqlite3 database. I have tried many methods to create the horizontal tableview and worked nice but when I pass the objects to table view to be displayed on the cells, the app crashes.

I got error that I googled and found that table view is accessing an object from the array that did not exist.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < colors.count; i++) {
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    self.tableView = tableView;
    tableView.dataSource = self;


    [self.scrollView addSubview:tableView];
```

And in `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender` I am passing the array's objects to a particular page when the page is scrolled.

Are there any other good methods to do this?

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use [NRGridView](https://github.com/ldesroziers/NRGridView), because as per my understanding you have multiple tableview in scrollview, that why tableview delegate method going to confused & your app gone crashed.

Comment: Thank u for the help . The requirement is paged horizontal scrolling . And I have to pass data from sqlite3 (data base) to particular page...plz can u sugest me some good methods with piece of code